# mongoose virtual count field: this.populate().execPopulate() field is null when accessed, unless .toJSON() is called on populated doc first

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

### What I expect to happen:

After populating `this` with `populate().execPopulate()` through either `async/await` (assigned to `populatedDoc`) or `.then(populatedDoc => )`:

- logging `this` or the `populatedDoc` shows the field and its correct value
- logging `this.fieldName` or `populatedDoc.fieldName` returns the correct value
- logging `this.toJSON().fieldName` or `populatedDoc.toJSON().fieldName` returns the correct value

### What is actually happening:

After populating `this` with `populate().execPopulate()` through either `async/await` (assigned to `populatedDoc`) or `.then(populatedDoc => )`:

- logging `this` or the `populatedDoc` shows the field and its correct value
- logging `this.fieldName` or `populatedDoc.fieldName` returns `null`
- if I log `this.toJSON().fieldName` or `populatedDoc.toJSON().fieldName` the correct value is returned

### Schema (simplified)

```
const storySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      title: String,
      body: String,
      publishedDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: null,
      },
      published: { // true: published, false: draft
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      author: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
      parent: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'stories' },
    }, { timestamps: true });

storySchema.virtual('repliesCount', {
  ref: 'stories', // collection name this field references
  localField: '_id', // the ID to of this story
  foreignField: 'parent', // the field on the Story document to match with the ID
  count: true, // only return a count of documents
});

const Story = mongoose.model('stories', storySchema);
```

### Instance Method

I then have a method where I use the `repliesCount` field. I have simplified the method as an example. I tried using both async/await and traditional .then():

```
storySchema.methods.test = async function test() {
  this.populate('repliesCount')
    .execPopulate()
    .then((updatedDoc) => {
      console.log(this); // repliesCount field: 1
      console.log(this.repliesCount); // null
      console.log(this.toJSON().repliesCount); // 1

      console.log(updatedDoc); // repliesCount field: 1
      console.log(updatedDoc.repliesCount); // null ??
      console.log(updatedDoc.toJSON().repliesCount); // 1
    });


  const populatedDoc = await this.populate('repliesCount').execPopulate();
  console.log(populatedDoc); // repliesCount field: 1
  console.log(populatedDoc.repliesCount); // null ??
  console.log(populatedDoc.toJSON().repliesCount); // 1
}
```

### Instance Method Output Logs

```
console.log models/story.js:146
    { publishedDate: 2018-12-29T00:37:46.267Z,
      published: true,
      _id: 5c26c1da02fb5f2303f071e0,
      author:
       { followers: [],
         following: [],
         _id: 5c26c1da02fb5f2303f071de,
         username: 'linnea',
         avatarURL: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/yigitpinarbasi/128.jpg',
         createdAt: 2018-12-29T00:37:46.145Z,
         updatedAt: 2018-12-29T00:37:46.145Z,
         __v: 0 },
      title: 'Multi-tiered mobile moratorium',
      body: 'Ut est laborum iure facilis. Voluptate dolores id accusamus. Delectus itaque qui harum occaecati. Consequatur deserunt harum repellendus est ut.\n \rDolorem in nostrum. Quae accusamus tempore eum. Vel sequi ipsam cupiditate excepturi iusto quis. Quam voluptatum aperiam laudantium sit eveniet nisi deserunt cumque. Qui architecto libero aut ipsa quae est saepe ipsam.',
      parent: null,
      createdAt: 2018-12-29T00:37:46.230Z,
      updatedAt: 2018-12-29T00:37:46.268Z,
      __v: 0,
      repliesCount: 1 }

  console.log models/story.js:147
    null

  console.log models/story.js:148
    1
```

Comment: i opened an issue on mongoose with some test cases illustrating my issue. hoping to continue the discussion on there https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7380

Comment: this turned out to be a bug. I confirmed it with some unit tests in the above issue. it was fixed in the latest (5.4.9) release